# Log4jNode in Message flow in Websphere Message Broker is throwing error

Tags: log4j, websphere, messagebroker

I am developing a simple message flow which uses Log4j to log the status at various stages. But when I am trying to run this flow I am getting the following error. I have use Log4jNode in the message flow.

An error occurred when trying to resolve the Java class or method `''com.ibm.broker.IAM3.Log4jNode.initLog4j''` which is referred to by the routine ''**initLog4j**''

As the error message states, I guess it couldn't find the reference for the log4jNode. But I couldn't find any help which could nail this down. Experts please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Log4jNode](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021221) is one of the [Category 2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg27007198#2) - unsupported Websphere MQ SupportPacs. This is sort of a compute node used to configure and write log files. The error has occured during initialization.

As you have guessed, there seems to be a trouble finding the reference jar in MQ Broker's classpath. Please check the documentation found [here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/iam3.pdf) and see if you have missed anything.

Comment: I have copied the _jar_ files already in the correct locations as described in the PDF this time I am getting a **different** error. Are there **any more** configurations apart from the jar files?

Comment: If I correctly recollect, there are a couple of more files `broker.xml` and `log4j.dtd` to be placed somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot I think it is available in the **samples** folder of the SupportPacs download.